# How can I fetch ID from multiple tag selected from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

Actully I have 3 tables **mail**, **tags** and **tag_assigned**

I am using filter query of multiple tag selected mail list.

**For e.g.** : From the screenshot I need to fetch `mailid` from  this table where selected tags `id` 1 and 2.

I want to return `mailid` 4 and 1. How to get these ids from this table.

I need sql query for this...

Screen Shot:
[image]

Comment: Show your Query..

Comment: please clear more and show your query

Comment: IF mail_id and tag_id columns are in mail table,  then use `SELECT DISTINCT mail_id FROM mail WHERE tag_id IN(1,2);`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to achieve this. Following query will be useful to you,

```
select a.mail_id from your_table_name a
join your_table_name b on a.mail_id = b.mail_id
where a.tag_id = 1 and b.tag_id = 2
```